# Can I use a concatenated string for the url in my .ajax() request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm doing cross-domain requests and once the first request is made I need to retrieve the ID (and do some other stuff) and then use the ID for the next request.

So far the hang-up is that the next request doesn't like the concatenation. Here's my code, and yes I know document.write should be changed to console.log() however console.log doesn't work and I was probably going to ask that question after get help with my current problem. the problem starts at the second .ajax() request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script >
$(document).ready(function($) {
 // First link out of three
 var url = 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalo
/items?parentId=504108e5e4b07a90c5ec62d4&max=60&offset=0&format=jsonp';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
    for (var i = 36; i < 37; i++) {
        document.write(json.items[i].id);
            var urlId = json.items[i].id;
    }

        var deferUrl = 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink/" + urlId 
+"?format=json&max=10';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: deferUrl,
                jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(json) {
                    // Get the next id to use for the next url

                    document.write(deferUrl);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog
/item/4f4e4b19e4b07f02db6a7f04?format=jsonp',
                        jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        success: function(json) {
                        document.write(json.title); 
                        },
                        error: function(e) {
                            console.log(e.message);
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            });
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: As for `console.log`, press F12 on Chrome/IE and choose the Console tab. Firefox has the native console (Ctrl+Shift+K) and the much better [Firebug plugin](https://getfirebug.com/) (install it and press F12).

Comment: You're mixing double and single quotes... If you consistently used one or the other throughout your code based on the situation you wouldn't run into that issue.

Comment: @Kevin thanks, I got that fixed but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will have any effect, but never use document.write after the document is ready unless you really know what you are doing. Instead, use console.log(), alert(), or an element that you can append text/elements to.

Comment: @Kevin, for testing purposes I was using document.write since I couldn't get console.log() to work. I'm installing firebug like Fabricio suggested and then make the change. I tried alert and still the same problem though. It doesn't seem to like the concatenation and I don't know if it has to do with it being cross domain???

Comment: cross-domain shouldn't be an issue considering you are using jsonp, as long as the api supports jsonp the way you are using it.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Thanks for the info, I've installed firebug and will try that out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made a slight change from

```
for (var i = 36; i < 37; i++) {
            var urlId = json.items[i].id;
    }

 var deferUrl = 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink/' + 
 urlId + '?format=jsonp&max=10';

$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: deferUrl,
                jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
```

to

```
for (var i = 36; i < 37; i++) {
           var urlId = json.items[i].id;
    }

var deferUrl = urlId;

$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink/' + 
                deferUrl + '?format=jsonp&max=10',
                jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
```

and that seemed to do the trick. It didn't like having the concatenation done completely before assigning it to the url.

Answer (score 2):

```
'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink/" + urlId 
+"?format=json&max=10';
```

should be

```
'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink/' + urlId 
+'?format=json&max=10';
```

You mix simples and doubles quotes. use `'srting' + var + 'string'` or `"string" + var + "string"` but don't mix them

Comment: That is, your single/double quotes are unbalanced at that line

Comment: Thanks flow, I fixed the quotes. I hadn't noticed that, although it's still won't work for some reason?? It finishes the first request and then just hangs without moving on.

Comment: is your first ajax resquest success ?

Comment: @flow Yes it is successful and I think I found the problem with the second request. I'm going to run some more tests and then post my answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

To address your concatenation issue only.. you have a mix of single and double quotes there. They should all be consistent.

ex:

```
var deferUrl = 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink/' + urlId + '?format=json&max=10';
```